# Insert multiple values into hidden field

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select list, where you can choose multiple cities - When choosing a city, i wanna add the Zipcode to a hidden field, the solution i have now inserts the value to the hidden field, however, it overwrites the value when fx: clicking a new city - It should just append to the value, like: value="value1|value2|value3"

```
 $jq('.select-cities').click(function () {
    var zipcodeValue = $jq(this).val();
    //alert(zipcodeValue);
    $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenAreas').val(zipcodeValue);
    $jq('.select-cities option:selected').appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$jq('.select-cities').click(function () {
    var zipcodeValue = $jq(this).val();
    //alert(zipcodeValue);
    var oldVal = $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenAreas').val();
    $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenAreas').val(oldVal+"|"+ zipcodeValue);
    $jq('.select-cities option:selected').appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$jq('.select-cities').click(function () {
    var zipcodeValue = $.trim( this.value );
    $jq('.hiddenFieldChosenAreas').val(function(i, oldVal) {
       return oldVal + '|' + zipcodeValue;
    });
    $jq('option:selected', this).appendTo('.chosen-cities');
});
```