# Adding multiple values to hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing a script that grabs values from an autocomplete form and adds them to a hidden field, which is then processed in php and the values are added to the DB.

```
var oldVal = $("#models").val();
$("#models").val(oldVal+","+ searchcode);
```

Instead of overwriting the previous values i need it to store comma separated like this.
Say its 4 clicks it should be `value="123,1234,12345,123456"`
but instead it only stores the last value twice as such `value="123456,123456"`
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show more context to this? Where is searchcode determined? Is this all within some function?  IF so, show the whole function so it can be determined if there are scoping or hoisting issues.

Comment: I feel its similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944765/insert-multiple-values-into-hidden-field ? which is asked before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made a little improvement:

```
function appendWords()
{
    var resultObj = $("#result");
    var outputObj = $("#textbox");
    var stringToAppend = resultObj.val().length > 0 ? resultObj.val() + "," : "";
    resultObj .val( stringToAppend + outputObj.val() );
}
```

See this working:
http://jsfiddle.net/95hzx/1/

Comment: Follow up question, is there anyway to now search through the value field to delete specific keys?

Comment: Use `indexOf()` into value string, searching for the desired key to find a starting position. Then remove the chars between starting position plus the lenght of key. Got it?

Answer (score 2):

Write it in plain JS

```
document.getElementById('models').value += "," + searchcode;
```

Remember that jQuery is a tool to "write less - do more" As soon as you have a situation that requires you to write more it stops being the useful tool for the job.